# Como hacer que un botón me muestre un formulario?

Tags: javascript, html

En estos momentos estoy practicando con botones y forularios con 
 `javascript` y `html` quiero que cuando de click en el botón el formulario salga en un pop-up, así que leí sobre la `class=modal`e intente hacerlo pero nada en el momento está funcionando y estoy un poco confundida.

¿ Primero en que estoy haciendo mal, y segundo en como funciona un `modal` ?.

Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada ¡Gracias!

[Aquí pueden ver en lo que he trabajado hasta ahora](https://codepen.io/lina-paredes/pen/EGavev)

```js
function mostrarFormulario(){ 
  var formulario = document.getElementById('Formulario');
  formulario.style.display = "block";  
}


document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', isValid)

function isValid(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pass ="seahorse"    
    var password = document.getElementById("Password1");
    console.log(password);
    
    if (password.value.match(pass)){
        window.location.href = "HappyChristmas.html";    
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert('Nope, try again')
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
#capa3{
/*CIRCULO*/
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #e6ac00;
 font-size: 48px;
/*medidas*/
 left: 80%;
 bottom: 5%;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <input type=button id="capa3"  onclick="mostrarFormulario()" value="Let's start!"/>
 <div id="Formulario" style="display: none;" class="modal-content">
    <form name="PasswordField" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><h4>If you're an octopus I am...</h4></label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Para empezar: Fijate que en tu onclick estas llamando a mostrarFomulario() pero en tu js la funcion se llama mostrarFormulario, te falta la r en formulario en el index

Comment: Y despues estas haciendo que cambie el estilo del formulario a block pero va entre comillas porque sino el codigo piensa que es una variable y te dice que esta undefined, iria asi: formulario.style.display = "block"; ya arreglando el mostrarFormulario() y poniendo lo del estilo, el boton muestra el formulario al darle click

Comment: Aqui tambien hay fiddle para que puedas añadir tu código, el problema con los enlaces externos es que la información de esos enlaces podría desaparecer en un futuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en tu ejercicio solo vi dos errores

este es el Script que te fallo:

```
      function mostrarFomulario(){ 
      var formulario = document.getElementById('Formulario');
      formulario.style.display = "block";  
      }
```

1.-El nombre de la función no coincidía con el de la función llamada en OnClick, es muy importante ver que nuestras funciones estén correctamente escritas.
2.-El valor de style.display debe estar entre comillas.

Como consejo: Cuando vayas a llamar una función copia y pega el nombre para evitar esto :)